# Populate available ports w.r.t serial (UART) communication

Tags: c++, qt, port, uart

I write a Qt code to find and list the available ports using serial communication Could anyone be kind enough to guide me through?

Comment: Use the Qt Examples: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-cenumerator-example.html or https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-enumerator-example.html

Answer (score 2):

To write a serial related application first of all you need to add qt serial module to your app by adding serialport to .pro file like this

```
QT  += core gui serialport
```

Then add the serial info header file to your code

```
#include <QtSerialPort/qserialportinfo.h>
```

And finally you can list available serial ports as below

```
foreach(QSerialPortInfo port, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts())
{
    qDebug()<<port.portName();
}
```